# Handler is not getting the requested data from AjaxUpload

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-ajax, ajax-upload

I have a code for image upload . I used **AjaxUpload.js** plugin for `uploading images without postback` . The problem is when i am passing hardcoded values (whether as query paramter or by `data` helper) , I am able to retrieve that in my handler . But when i am passing some generic value like `$('#some_id').val()` , then i always recieve empty string in my handler .

**SCRIPT**

```
  var upload='';
  upload = new AjaxUpload($('#fileOpenDialog'),
    {
        action:  RootPath + 'GraphicResourceHandlers/FileHandler.ashx',         
        data: { OldGraphicName: $('#hidGraphicName').val() },
        type: 'POST',         
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        autoSubmit: false,         
        onChange: function (file, extension) {

           //some code
        },
        onSubmit: function (file, response) {

            alert("Success.");
        },
        onError: function () {
            alert("Error in upload.");
        },
        onComplete: function (file, response) {

            //some code 
          }
    });


   //upload image 
     $('#btnUpload').click(function () {

        //This will call the AjaxUpload .
        upload.submit();

         //Hides the modal that asks for uploading image
        $('#browseFile').modal('hide');
     });
```

**FileHandler.ashx**

```
   public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            context.Response.ContentType = " text/html";        

            //This line is returning an empty string         
            context.Request["OldGraphicName"]

           //I also did this while passing as a query paramter but no luck
            context.Request.QueryString["OldGraphicName"]

            string graphicPath = Config.GraphicsPath;
            string locationPath = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + graphicPath;
            string fileName = context.Request.Files[0].FileName;
            string newFileName = Guid.NewGuid() + Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            context.Request.Files[0].SaveAs(locationPath + newFileName);
            context.Response.Write(newFileName);

        }
    }
```

Can someone please look into this issue . I really toiled hard to figure out what is wrong on my part .

Thanks !

Comment: I am able to upload images on server by this `script` with unique names . The thing is now i need to rename the newly uploaded file with the old one .For that i am keeping the old image name in a hidden field and passing it as a paramter through AjaxUpload to the handler .

Comment: @Pete ??  I forgot to reference you while adding my comment

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this..

```
var fileOpenDialog= $("#fileOpenDialog").val();
```

and in ajax

```
data: {OldGraphicName: fileOpenDialog}
```

sorry if i was wrong....

Comment: you didn't see my code properly . I am not passing `fileOpenDialog` value to the handler , rather i am passing a hidden field value `$('#hidGraphicName').val() ` . This is not the value of the uploading image but the value of the image that already exists on the server . I want to change the name of the uploading image with this value i.e. `$('#hidGraphicName').val() `